# How can i configure clang format without .clang-format file in every workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I want to configure clang-format without having to copy my `.clang-format` file to every new workspace.

In my `settings.json` I currently have

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "{BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, IndentCaseLabels: false, TabWidth: 4, UseTab: ForIndentation, ColumnLimit: 0}",
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Google"
```

The description for `C_Cpp.clang_format_style` says

> Coding style, currently supports: Visual Studio, LLVM, Google, Chromium, Mozilla, WebKit. Use "file" to load the style from a .clang-format file in the current or parent directory. Use "{key: value, ...}" to set specific parameters, e.g.: "{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, IndentWidth: 8 }"

Which made me think my approach would work, which it doesn't. When I use the auto format it always uses the Google fallbackStyle.

Is this just not possible or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: To get clang-format running, I roughly did the following (off the top of my head, hopefully not too wrong): I installed and activated (!) Clang-Format extension by xaver and then configured it like `"clang-format.style": "{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, IndentWidth: 2, Standard: Cpp11}"`.

Comment: the formatter will go up in the file system until it will find a `.clag-format` or `_clang.format` in some ancestor directory. You could put that file in the $HOME directory and every project will use it.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `clang-format -style=file` is somewhat misleading.

You need to define the following in your `settings.json` (either workspace or global)

```
{
   "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "file",
}
```

As file is not the path to the file you want but rather tells clang-format to use the `.clang-format` file it can find within the local path - going all the way up (`cd ..` until it can find one).

If the case is the VSCode C++ extension own `clang-format` it's in the VSCode extensions folder.

Which should make the `clang-format` to go `cd ..` until it finds.clang-format` in your code folder (if one exists).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found that your approach using (I have changed only the formatting)

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "{BasedOnStyle: Google, 
IndentWidth: 4, 
IndentCaseLabels: false, 
TabWidth: 4, UseTab: ForIndentation, 
ColumnLimit: 0}",
```

does work.

Comment: I had to reference [where to find the settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) to make use of this.