# Q: Can I configure VSCode to take a .clang-format file from my home directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I want to use the same clang-format file for all my project since I have multiple. But I don't want to have them in every workspace and i already have a clang-format file in my home directory, how can I make this work?
Or is this impossible?

I have already seen this question:
[How can i configure clang format without .clang-format file in every workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380136/how-can-i-configure-clang-format-without-clang-format-file-in-every-workspace)

but my clang-format file is like 80 lines long and I just want to edit the stuff locally on my home without having to change it in vscode as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

The `clang-format -style=file` is somewhat misleading.

`file` is not the path to the file you want but rather tells `clang-format` to use the `.clang-format` file it can find within the project folders - going all the way up.

And as VSCode is the case, the C++ extension is using by default the `clang-format` in the VSCode extensions folder.
Which should make the `clang-format` to go `cd ..` until it finds `.clang-format` in your workspace folder

Comment: As of `clang-format` 15 full file path can be specified with the `--style` option using `--style=file:<file name>`

Answer (score 5):

Set `"clang-format.style": "file"` property to fix it.