# Configuring VSC clang format with global.clang-format file

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, clang, clang-format

I basically have a similiar question to this one:
[How can i configure clang format without .clang-format file in every workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380136/how-can-i-configure-clang-format-without-clang-format-file-in-every-workspace)

I'm using the Visual Studio Code editor (version 1.43) with the Clang-Format extension developed by Xaver (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format#overview)

I adjusted the clang extension settings "Clang-format: Executable" option to point to the "clang-format.exe" of my VSC installation.
Furthermore I set "Clang-format: Style" to "file".

My clang-file is currently located inside my projects source folder.
As I want to use my clang settings for every project and don't want to copy the clang file into every project workspace manually (and maybe have to change every single copy later on), I tried to make the extension use a globally located clang-file which is inside the VSCs extention folder.

So my first approach was to relocate the clang-file into the "VSC 1.43\data" directory.
My second attempt was to locate it right inside the extension folder "C:\User\VSC 1.43\data\extensions\xaver.clang-format-1.9.0" where a default file was already present.

Unfortunately both attempts seem not to work. I can invoke the formatting with "Format Document" but another clang file seems to get utilized.
Only if I put the file back into the source code directory, my clang rules are getting utilized correctly.

So basically:

MyProject\SourceCode\clang-file --> Works

VSC\data\clang-file --> Doesn't work

VSC\data\extensions\xaver.clang-format-1.9.0\clang-file --> Doesn't work

Can I tell the extension to search for the clang file inside of the extensions installation directory instead of the current workspace?

Note: I just installed the clang-format extension and adjusted the mentioned extension settings above. I did not tamper with the VSC settings.json.

Thank you in advance and best regards :)

Evox402

Comment: Ok, for some reason my "Hello :) " gets removed from my post and can not be added. Didn't want to omit the initial greetings :)

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configuring-style-with-clang-format):

> When using -style=file, clang-format for each input file will try to find the .clang-format file located in the closest parent directory of the input file. When the standard input is used, the search is started from the current directory.

Actually I believe it searches for either `.clang-format` or `_clang_format`.

This explains:

> MyProject\SourceCode\clang-file --> Works

You could move the `.clang-format` file to `MyProject`, or any parent directory above that, so that it is shared between projects.